# Azure subscription re-enabled but VM stopped answering on port 80

Tags: azure, iis, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

I have an issue with a VM on Azure that serves a website and a web app.

My bizspark subscription spending limit ran out with one day to go, so I removed the spending limit for the subscription and all my services came back up.

However - the azure vm has stopped responding on port 80.  I can remote in on port 3389 but any pings to these sites or the server itself does not respond.  I can confirm the following:

- IIS is running
- The sites have started in IIS
- Port 80 is enabled in firewall
- Port 80 outbound is enabled in firewall
- Rebooted the server without issue
- Event log is empty except for an entry referencing ESENT - can't access api.log
- Services are all running
- Server can communicate out on port 80 to other websites
- Browsing from azure to the ip on port 80 shows a 404 not found
- Pinging server results in Request timed out

I am presuming that something hasn't re-enabled after microsoft disabled my subscription but can't figure out what.

Has anyone had a similar experience?

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.

For some reason azure has issued my vm a new public IP.

Would have found it much earlier but thought surely they wouldn't reissue my  IP... and they did.  Time to redo all my A records d'oh!

Comment: In the new preview portal (portal.azure.com) you can set reserved IP adresses for your VMs. Currently the first five reserved IP adresses are free (see http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/ip-addresses/).

Comment: Thanks peter - I'll check it out, will definitely save me some hassles.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm about given points.

- Check that port 80 entry should be available in firewall configuration of VM in azure portal(not taking about inside the the VM )
- please check the application is available in your VM. if not then please again deploy the application and store it in external drive provided in VM do not use C:
- please check the Public IP of VM is available or not.

if there is know issue with above points,so if possible please delete and Recreate the VM, that will solve your issue.